# How to declare an inner interface in a class with it's method signatures?

Tags: apex

When I do this the code throws no error,

```
public class MyClass {    

    interface MyInnerInterface {}

    public Integer x = 0;

}
```

But when i try to add a method to the inner interface it throws error,

```
public class MyClass {    

    interface MyInnerInterface {public void fun();}

    public Integer x = 0;

}
```

How to declare an inner interface in a class with it's method signatures ? Also, are inner interface private when no access modifier specified ? I know they have to be public or global when declared at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces do not specify a method access level. Take out the word `public`. If this interface should be accessible outside the class, you do need to specify an access level greater than `private`.

```
public class MyClass {    

    // Can only be used in this class
    interface MyPrivateInnerInterface {
      void fun();
    }
    // Can be used in any class in the namespace
    public interface MyPublicInnerInterface {
      void fun();
    }
    // Can be used in any namespace!!!
    global interface MyGlobalInnerInterface {
      void fun();
    }

    public Integer x = 0;

}
```